# How can I extract the value from this SimpleXml?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

How can I extract the value from this SimpleXml? I keep getting an empty array, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I just want to extract the string `"Familial GI Stromal Tumor With Loss of Heterozygosity and Amplification of Mutant KIT."`.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(5) "Title"
    ["Type"]=>
    string(6) "String"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(86) "Familial GI Stromal Tumor With Loss of Heterozygosity and Amplification of Mutant KIT."
}
```

Comment: What value do you need?

Comment: What are you doing that gets you an empty array?

Comment: Familial GI Stromal Tumor With Loss of Heterozygosity and Amplification of Mutant KIT.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to show us two things: the XML you're parsing (**not** the debug output from SimpleXML) and the PHP code you currently have (which is giving you the wrong result).

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXMLElement` has a `__toString()` method. For the element you showed in your question, you should be able to just echo the string content.

```
echo $yourElement;
```

or if you want it in a variable, you can call `__toString()` explicitly

```
$someVar = $yourElement->__toString();
```

or trigger it by treating the element as a string;

```
$someVar = "$yourElement";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it into a string.

```
var_dump((string) $element);
```

Anyway, it depends on your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone. Turns out I figured it out. I simply had to access it from the array.

```
 $title = $pub->xpath('Item[@Name="Title"]')[0];
```